# How can I separate the string using space in 1 column? example from "JohnDoe" into "John Doe"

Tags: postgresql

How can I separate the string using space in 1 column? example from "JohnDoe" into "John Doe"
Table Name is employee
Column name is name

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, [see](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=6f4d1e7cc6891064307be721789638b1)

```
SELECT regexp_replace('JohnDoe', '([A-Z])', ' \1', 'g');
```

In your case,

```
SELECT regexp_replace(name, '([A-Z])', ' \1', 'g') from employee;
```

Comment: it didnt work, error "function regxp_replace(character varying, unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist"

Comment: code is this // SELECT regxp_replace(column,'([A-Z])', '\1', 'g')
FROM table

Comment: what do you mean by code is this? how it differs from my solution?